# How to calculate x and y of any object inside an image when strech?

Tags: css, image, image-processing, formula

Suppose a image has

```
Height = 200px;
Width = 100px;
```

A point in that image which has

```
Y axis = 40px
X axis = 30px
```

Now if I resize that image:

```
New Height = 300px;
New Width = 150px;
```

> Is there any formula to calculate new Y and X axis of that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the factor that the coordinate change is:

xFactor = newSizeX/OldSizeX = 150/100 = 3/2

yactor = newSizeY/OldSizeY = 300/200 = 3/2

newXcoordinate = oldXCorrdainte*xFactor = 30*3/2 = 45

newYcoordinate = oldXCorrdainte*xFactor = 40*3/2 = 60